# SQL Server Reporting Services report generation error: rsProcessingAborted, rsDataExtensionNotFound

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

**Environment**: Windows 7 Professional 64bit, SQL Server Express 2014 64bit with Advanced Services, Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

I imported some MS Access reports to SQL Server Express 2014 Reporting Services. The report runs fine in VS2013 but when I run the report in the Report Manager by just clicking the report in the Reports folder, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'OLEDB' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)
```

I can see the entry for 'OLEDB' in the Extensions node of the the reportserver.config file.
What could be causing the error and how can we remedy it.

**EDIT 1**:
After migrating the reports from Access Db I changed the Db connections to local SQLEXPRESS Db. The reports are connecting to the local SQLEXPRESS db and are displaying the data fine inside Visual Studio 2013.

**EDIT 2**:

I downloaded the report from the Report Manager and opened it XML mode and noticed that the Data Source of the report is actually is the Access Db that I imported the report from. According to a comment from Sébastien Sevrin `SSRS in SQL EXPRESS does not support Access Db as a Data Source`, hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing the error?

The cause of this error is that SQL Server Express only supports Datasources located in the Local SQL Server instance.

> How can we remedy it?

You have 2 options:

- Upgrade to a Standard version of SQL Server at least
- Target a supported data-source (SQL Express)

More info: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've added `EDIT` at the end of my original post. I'm actually connecting to the local `SQLEXPRESS` Db. I created the Data-Source in the `Shared Data Sources` folder with the connection string: `
Data Source=MyDesktop\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDb`

Comment: @nam - Is the Reporting Services instance on `MyDesktop` as well?

Comment: Yes. Everything is on `MyDesktop`. No remote connections.

Comment: @nam - Can you try to use `Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDb` instead?

Comment: using localhost in the Data Source did not work either. I downloaded the report from the Report Manager and opened the report file (that is an XML) in an XML editor and noticed that the report actually points to the `Access Db` I imported it from. `Does SQL Express supports Access Db as a data source`?

Comment: @nam - No, only a local SQL Express instance

Comment: That explains. I added EDIT 2 in my original post. You can point that to in your original response and I'll then mark your response as an Answer.